# Duplicate Conditions in PostgreSQL Query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

Can using duplicate conditions in PostgreSQL cause any problems?

For example, I have a purchases table with a customer id, and my framework in some cases duplicates a lookup condition, like the example below.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM purchases p
WHERE p.customer_id = 123 
AND p.customer_id = 123;
```

OR

```
SELECT p.*
FROM purchases p
WHERE p.customer_id = 123 
AND p.salesman = 456 
AND p.departament = 789 
AND p.customer_id = 123;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that can cause bad query estimates. If PostgreSQL thinks that `WHERE p.customer_id = 123` will return 10% of the rows from the table, it will think that `WHERE p.customer_id = 123 AND p.customer_id = 123` will only return 1% of the table, because it does not realize that the conditions are actually the same and treats them as statistically independent.

Bad estimates can lead to bad plan choices and bad performance.

Perhaps that does not matter so much in your case: PostgreSQL puts a lower limit of 1 on each row count estimate, so if your de-duplicated query is already estimated to return very few rows, not much harm will be done.

Try using `EXPLAIN`!

Comment: Are you sure about this? When I run explain on a query with the same value multiple times, postgresql only show one compare, not 2.

Comment: @MTilsted You'd have to show what you mean. With `IN`, there will be one comparison, but the duplicate value won't be removed, and the estimate will be affected.

Answer (score 2):

According to my tests on 12.6, it depends on the predicate:

```
db=# explain select * from books where product_form = 'BB';
                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Index Scan using index_books_on_client_id_and_product_form on books  (cost=0.29..7273.75 rows=3604 width=23686)
  Index Cond: ((product_form)::text = 'BB'::text)
(2 rows)

db=# explain select * from books where product_form = 'BB' and product_form = 'BB' ;
                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Index Scan using index_books_on_client_id_and_product_form on books  (cost=0.29..7273.75 rows=3604 width=23686)
  Index Cond: ((product_form)::text = 'BB'::text)
(2 rows)

db=# explain select * from books where product_form = 'BB' and product_form = 'BB' and product_form = 'BB' ;
                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Index Scan using index_books_on_client_id_and_product_form on books  (cost=0.29..7273.75 rows=3604 width=23686)
  Index Cond: ((product_form)::text = 'BB'::text)
(2 rows)
```

So in that case, no problem. The row estimate and costs are constant.

Possibly this is because an index is involved, because an ilike predicate is negatively affected by this:

```
db=# explain select * from books where title ilike '%phys%';
                          QUERY PLAN                          
--------------------------------------------------------------
Seq Scan on books  (cost=0.00..7613.31 rows=539 width=23686)
  Filter: ((title)::text ~~* '%phys%'::text)
(2 rows)

db=# explain select * from books where title ilike '%phys%' and  title ilike '%phys%';
                                      QUERY PLAN                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Seq Scan on books  (cost=0.00..7676.98 rows=11 width=23686)
  Filter: (((title)::text ~~* '%phys%'::text) AND ((title)::text ~~* '%phys%'::text))
(2 rows)

db=# explain select * from books where title ilike '%phys%' and  title ilike '%phys%' and title ilike '%phys%';
                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Seq Scan on books  (cost=0.00..7740.64 rows=1 width=23686)
  Filter: (((title)::text ~~* '%phys%'::text) AND ((title)::text ~~* '%phys%'::text) AND ((title)::text ~~* '%phys%'::text))
(2 rows)
```

Note the slight increase in cost and the reductction in estimate row count.

I think this could well be version sensitive also, so I would suggest checking is on your version with the predicates and schema that you're concerned with.